# Fastest way to delete values witch no match in a collection

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table with roughly 2000 entries containing a single integers value.

My application recreates these values where maybe 3 or 4 entries are different from the values I have already saved in the table. **My goal now is to delete all keys in the table which are not present in my newly created dataset**. What would be the best (fastest) way to handle this task?

1. Do I go ahead and drop the entire table and insert all new values with prepared statements and a batch request?
2. Do I write a really long query

   ```
   SELECT hashID WHERE hashID = x0 OR hashID =x1 OR hashID = x2000
   ```

   I can imagine that chaining multiple ORs together is quite expensive but maybe the database has a good optimization I am not aware of
3. are there any other queries I am not aware of?